# Data help and tips

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, relationship

I tried to make a calender visual, like here in the forum that I posted. Unfortunatelly I don't see an other option than Restructuring my data.
My currently data is as following

```
Project ID | Start Phase | Planning Phase | Execution Phase | Monitor Phase | live
22193      | 18-01-2021  | 20-01-2021     | 28-01-2021      | 20-02-2021    | 03-03-2021
29193      | 20-01-2021  | 10-02-2021     | 15-02-2021      | 19-03-2021    | 
87596      | 25-02-2021  | 10-03-2021     | 25-03-2021      | 30-03-2021    | 10-04-2021
```

And I think my restructured data will be as followed.

```
Phase ID |  Project ID |  Phase |     |Start    |   | End |
1        |  22193      |  Start |     |18-1-2021|   |20-1-2021 
2        |  22193      |  Planning|   |20-1-2021|   |28-1-2021
3        |  22193      |  Execition|  |28-1-2021|   |20-2-2021
4        |  22193      |  Monitor |   |20-2-2021|   |03-03-202
5        |  22193      |  Live |      |         |   |03-03-2021
```

My question is: Is there a way to add phases in my data with every Project ID in Power BI (Dax, M Or tables?). Because doing it manualy whill take for ever.

And a sidequestion, will this restructuing my data affecy my sql database?

Edit:
The top structure did not meet my needs because I want to make a calendar visual in Power BI. Unfortunatey there is no visual which accepts multiple dates, The current visuals in Power Bi only accepts 1 start and 1 end date. That is the reason to restructure my data to be able to have 1 start and 1 end date

yours faithfully

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Currently I am only using Excel sheets and no database. But in the furture I wil use mysql

Comment: In your restructure, there is nothing stopping you having things like another start record bank in the middle of the dataset. Perhaps you should explain why the top structure did not meet your needs

Comment: The top structure did not meet my needs because I want to make a calendar visual in Power BI. Unfortunatey there is no visual which accepts multiple dates, The current visuals in Power Bi only accepts 1 start and 1 end date. That is the reason to restructure my data to be able to have 1 start and 1 end date

Comment: To "add phases in my data with every Project ID " you effectively want to do the same as a SQL `partition by`. Some suggestions here https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-to-add-Row-number-over-partition-by-Customer-DAX-or-M-query/m-p/566949 and here https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2018/06/27/number-rows-by-group-using-power-query/

Comment: For now, thank you. I will have a look in the information that you have provided.